# Can I update an existing Push Notification in Background?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I read about it and just saw I can't remove the notification, but about update a notification, can I?

Comment: What do you mean, you can't remove a notification? You actually can do it. And no, you cannot modify a notification that is already delivered to the notification centre.

Comment: How can I remove a notification from the notification centre, then? @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 1):

You actually can remove notifications that are delivered to the notification centre, but you cannot modify them.

```
let nc = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
nc.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() //use if you want to remove all delivered notifications
nc.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String]) //use if you want to remove specific delivered notifications
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I expressed myself wrong, I want know, if I can modify or delete a sent notification in background of my app.